# Unable to call the os.environ from wsadmin using jython in WebSphere 6.x?

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I am trying to make a generic script for WebSphere 6.0, 6.1.x and 7 environments. What I need is to read some environment variables of my own that I need to use in the script for which I have been using the os.environ.get['MYVAR']. It works find on a WebSphere 7 and 6.1.x environment. But for a WebSphere 6.0 environment, it gave me the following error :

```
AttributeError: class 'org.python.modules.os' has no attribute 'environ'
```

On searching, I found that many of the libraries were introduced as optional libraries in WebSphere 6.1.x onwards and are available under /opt/WebSphere../AppServer/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib but for WebSphere 6.0, it isn't.

I narrowed it down to the javaos.py and copied that to a shared location and passed the location using `-wsadmin_classpath` option so that it could be found, yet now it gives me another error (possibly its not finding it.)

```
ImportError: no module named javaos
```

What I need is to somehow be able to pass some environment variables seemlessly over WebSphere 6.0, 6.1.x and 7.0 or be able to find out if javaos.py has further dependencies that need to be resolved (the hard way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit based on @Husain Khambaty's comment:

1 - Copy the Jython libraries from WebSphere 6.1.x to 6.0 (Directory ex : ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/AppServer/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib). [More Info](http://webspherehacks.com/blog/?p=10)

2 - If you'd like to use any custom location for jython libraries (more suitable for situations where the current WP environment directory can not be changed), then you can tell wsadmin.sh to look for the libraries in the custom location by using the -javaoption "-Dpython.path="

Comment: Well I did have a look at this blog earlier. It didn't meet my need completely. 

What I was looking for was to be able to pass some custom env var or be able to use the WebSphere 6.1+ libs w/o having to put them under the default wsadmin path (${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/AppServer/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib). 

What I was also looking for was to be able to tell wsadmin.sh to look else where so that I can keep the libraries under a shared location for all my "zillion" environments. I did find a way to do this.

.... -javaoption "-Dpython.path=<new-location>" ... and it looks where I want it to.

Comment: Could you post an answer based on your comment? will be useful for others.

Comment: To answer the original question above - 
Copy the WP6.1 optional libraries that are required under ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/AppServer/optionalLibraries/jython/Lib. If you'd like to use any custom location, then you can tell wsadmin.sh to look for the libraries in the custom location by using the -javaoption "-Dpython.path=<custom-location>".